# How do I prove shoenflies theorem for $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I studied the contents in Munkres-Topology. In this text, the author uses basic algebraic topology to prove Jordan curve theorem. Then, he wrote that "If $C$ is a simple closed curve in $S^2$, the closure of a connected component of $S^2\setminus C$ is hoeomorphic to a closed unit ball $B^2$."

The author mentioned a reference text, but I this text does not use algebraic topology tools and it looks quite messy to me. I dislike it.

I know that there is a generalization of this theorem, but what I'm curious about is that: "With the theorems and machineries in Munkres' text proving Jordan curve theorem, can one prove the Shoenflies theorem for the case $S^2$ with a relatively little effort?"

If not, what would be a text proving this theorem for the case $S^2$ using algebraic topology tools, not using higher homotopy groups nor homology?

Comment: There is no such thing as a non-messy proof of Schoenflies. [Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-06/S0002-9939-1951-0046635-9/S0002-9939-1951-0046635-9.pdf) is, at least, a short proof.

Comment: @MikeMiller Using Riemann mapping theorem, it can be shown that the interior $V$ of the simple closed curve $C$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphic to a unit open ball in $\mathbb{C}$. Is it possible to extend this diffeomorphism to a homeomorphism $f:V\cup C\rightarrow B^2$?

Comment: Any homeomorphism you choose? No. Some homeomorphism? Yes, because that's the Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: @MikeMiller Schoenflies theorem asserts there exists an automorphism( homeomorphism ) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which maps a given simple closed curve to $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But I'm asking somewhat weaker than that. I'm only curious whether it is possible to prove **the closure of the interior** is homeomorphic to a closed ball.. by extending an arbitrary biholomorphism between $V$and a unit open ball.

Comment: The proof in Bing's 3-manifolds book is pretty nice and self-contained, and even works in the general case. Really even Brown's original paper was very, very short though there are certainly better presentations of it than his original paper.

Comment: @Rubertos: To finish that, you want Caratheodary's theorem. I probably wouldn't call that straightforward. The content is basically Fatou's theorem that $\lim_{r \to 1} f(re^{i\theta})$ exists for a set of $\theta$ dense in the unit circle for a bounded holomorphic unction $f$ on the unit disc.